# Laravel 5.2 required_without_all Request Issue

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having an issue with `required_without_all`. I have three elements, and at least **one** should be filled. My file input's name is `image[]`. Adding an image but leaving `title` and `body` empty still results in a validation error, even though it shouldn't.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title'   => 'required_without_all:body,image.*',
        'body'    => 'required_without_all:title,image.*',
        'image.*' => 'required_without_all:body,title',
    ];

}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'title.required_without_all'    => 'At least one field is required',
        'body.required_without_all'     => 'At least one field is required',
        'image.*.required_without_all'  => 'At least one field is required',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39089295/2101328

Basically, add `image` as an array and remove the `*` from the rules.

There was also a bug in Laravel 5.3 that prevented similar from working; see this thread: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15044#issuecomment-244364706

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title'   => 'required_without_all:body,image',
        'body'    => 'required_without_all:title,image',
        'image'   => 'array',
        'image.*' => 'required_without_all:body,title',
    ];
}
```