# Laravel 5.2 Validate File Array

Tags: validation, laravel

I have a form with three fields: `title`, `body` and `photo[]`. I'm trying to validate it so that at least one item is filled in, but I can't seem to get it to work. If I upload a file I still receive an error for `title` and `body`.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required_without_all:body,photo.*',
        'body' => 'required_without_all:title,photo.*',
        'photo.*' => 'required_without_all:title,body',
        'photo.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,gif,png',
    ];
}
```

**Update:** Jonathan pointed out that I had my rules wrong. I've fixed them and am now using this. It's still not working; when I try to upload a photo I get the error message that the other fields are required.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required_without:body,photo.*',
        'body' => 'required_without:title,photo.*',
        'photo.*' => 'required_without:title,body|mimes:jpeg,gif,png',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two rules for the same field? Please elaborate on what it is you're trying to do as I'm not completely clear but have made some assumptions in the first draft of my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to ensure the `photo` field is an array then you need `'photo' => 'array'` and then you can use `'photo.*' => ''` for the other validations of the array's children.

The rules are separated by a pipe character `|` so if you were going to combine the two in your example it would be `'photo.*' => 'required_without_all:title,body|mimes:jpeg,gif,png',`. I don't see you using the pipe to separate rules so I can't be sure you are aware of it.

This may have been where you were going wrong in the first place (two keys in the associative array that are identical) and some kind of precedence taking affect negating one of the rules.

You could try something like this (for the record I think you were on the right track to begin with using `required_without_all` as this stipulates the need to be required if *all* of the given fields are missing):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required_without_all:body,photo',
        'body' => 'required_without_all:title,photo',
        'photo' => 'array',
        'photo.*' => 'required_without_all:title,body|mimes:jpeg,gif,png',
    ];
}
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation)

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was bleary eyed and was setting up my rules like how you'd set up the messages: one line for each message. I fixed the rule and separated them with a pipe; it didn't help. I'm not sure what you mean by `'photo' => 'array'`?

Comment: To clarify: I want the user to fill in at least one field. So they have to upload a photo, or add a title, or add text to the body; they can not submit an empty form.

Comment: `'photo' => 'array'` just checks that your `photo` value is an array. Since you're sending n-photos each of which is encapsulated in the top-most array. So the first validation would be to ensure that you are receiving an array.

Comment: I grabbed your code and switched `photo.*` to `'photo.*' => '|required_without_all:title,body|mimes:jpeg,gif,png'` and it works! Thanks!